# ajaxterm using proportional font

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, Apache 2.4.7, Python 2.7.6 and Ajaxterm 0.10-12ubuntu1. Ajaxterm is proxied via Apache.

Here's the apache.conf excerpt:

```
# Suppresses the Via header
ProxyVia Off
# Do not flood the log
#CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined env=!dontlog
#SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/ajaxterm/u" dontlog

ProxyRequests Off
<Proxy *>
       Order deny,allow
       Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyPass /ajaxterm/ http://localhost:8022/ retry=0
ProxyPassReverse /ajaxterm/ http://localhost:8022/ retry=0
```

When it was initially installed, Ajaxterm worked fine. Now, however, it uses a proportional font instead:
[image: Ajaxterm]

I've uninstalled and reinstalled it, but I can't figure out what the problem is. No errors appear in the browser console or network inspector.

Answer (score 4):

An interim answer that's working for me is to change the browser's default font to a monospace  font.  That sucks as a long term solution, but does hint that the problem is something to do with the ajaxterm CSS where it's suggesting that the browser use a mono font.  Still researching.

```
pre.stat {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 4px;
        display: block;
        font-family: monospace;
        white-space: pre;
        background-color: black;
        border-top: 1px solid black;
        color: white;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. AjaxTerm hasn't changed in years. I wonder what change underneath (Apache?) is causing this broken behaviour.

Comment: Yep, probably not AjaxTerm.  I think it's far more likely that the browsers have changed in how they handle the CSS request..